# After upgrading to Django 3.2 my annotations on `ArrayAgg` fields not working

Tags: python, django, postgresql

[UPDATE] The relevant models (thinned):

```
class Contact(TimeStampedModel, ComputedFieldsModel):
    ....  # Irrelevant, see reverse lookups on RegisteredStaffContact
```

```
class RegisteredStaffContact(TimeStampedModel):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, models.CASCADE, related_name='registered_staffing')
    staff_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.CASCADE, related_name='contact_registered_staffing')
    is_primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ....
```

```
class User(TimeStampedModel, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ....
    assistants = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, related_name='principals')
    .... used in the method in question under variable user_principals_ids
```

```
class ShareRequest(TimeStampedModel):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(to=Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='share_requests')
    ....

    @classmethod
    def get_inbox_for_user(cls, user: User) -> 'models.QuerySet[ShareRequest]':
        user_principals_ids = list(user.principals.values_list('id', flat=True))

        annotated_share_requests = cls._default_manager\
            .annotate(
                registered_staff_ids=ArrayAgg(
                    'contact__registered_staffing__staff_user',
                    distinct=True,
                )
            )\
            .annotate(
                primary_registered_staff_ids=ArrayAgg(
                    'contact__registered_staffing__staff_user',
                    filter=models.Q(contact__registered_staffing__is_primary=True),
                    distinct=True,
                )
            )

        filtered_shared_requests = annotated_share_requests\
            .filter(
                (models.Q(primary_registered_staff_ids__isnull=True) & models.Q(registered_staff_ids__contains=[user.id]))
                | (models.Q(primary_registered_staff_ids__isnull=True) & models.Q(registered_staff_ids__overlap=user_principals_ids))
                | models.Q(primary_registered_staff_ids__contains=[user.id])
                | models.Q(primary_registered_staff_ids__contained_by=user_principals_ids)
            )

        return filtered_shared_requests
```

Skipping the details, the important part is my annotate statements and further filtering by them.

From the example below, you can see that `registered_staff_ids` results in `[None]`, which looks like a part of the problem:

```
In [39]: annotated_share_requests.first().registered_staff_ids
Out[39]: [None]
```

I was able to remedy it by providing an additional filter to my annotate statement, turning that expression into:

```
annotated_share_requests = cls._default_manager\
    .annotate(
        registered_staff_ids=ArrayAgg(
            'contact__registered_staffing__staff_user',
            filter=models.Q(contact__registered_staffing__staff_user__isnull=False),
            distinct=True,
        )
    )\
    ...
```

Which now shows the result as:

```
In [40]: annotated_share_requests.first().registered_staff_ids
Out[40]: []
```

However, the further filtering (specifically `__overlap` and `__contained_by` lookups fail, for example:

```
In [56]: annotated_share_requests.values_list('primary_registered_staff_ids', flat=True)
Out[56]: <QuerySet [[], []]>  # looks great

In [57]: annotated_share_requests.values_list('registered_staff_ids', flat=True)
Out[57]: <QuerySet [[], []]>  # looks great

In [58]: user_principals_ids
Out[58]: []  # looks great

# BUT!

In [59]: annotated_share_requests.filter(registered_staff_ids__overlap=user_principals_ids)
Out [59]: FieldError: Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field

# AND SIMILARLY!

In [61]: annotated_share_requests.filter(primary_registered_staff_ids__contained_by=user_principals_ids)
Out [62]: FieldError: Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field
```

What's interesting is that it only seems to be an issue with an empty array on the right side of comparison, so this works:

```
In [76]: annotated_share_requests.filter(primary_registered_staff_ids__contained_by=[1])
Out[76]: <QuerySet []>

In [77]: annotated_share_requests.filter(registered_staff_ids__overlap=[1])
Out[77]: <QuerySet []>
```

Looking for any pointers.

Comment: Can you share your models? Are the annotations important to return or do you just need the filtered results?

Comment: [UPDATE] @IainShelvington, adding models. I only care about the filtered results.